# Turning off Feature Classes in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, feature-class

I'm struggling to create a python script that will simply turn off all feature classes in the table of contents within my ArcGIS Pro project. I think part of my problem is the syntax change from ArcMap to Pro. I know that ESRI has a web page dedicated to that very issue (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm), but the diagram on that page just seems to confuse me more.

Here is my attempt at creating a script to to turn off feature classes in ArcGIS Pro.

```
import arcpy
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
for lyrx in arcpy.mp.ListLayers(p):
    print lyrx.name('')
    lyrx.visible = False
```

When I run the code above I receive the following message

```
File "<string>", line 4
  print lyrx.name('')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3.x, as such, the `print` command is a function. It requires you to use it like a function `print(lyrx.name)` where as in Python 2 you could get away with doing `print lyrx.name`

Note I've removed the ('')....I'm not sure what you're doing what that bit of code.

edit in regards to your comment:
The arcpy "mapping" syntax between ArcMap and Pro has changed in regards to arcpy "mp". You'll want to read the help, specifically the [map](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) and [layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) class.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\path\to\aprx.aprx")
m = aprx.listMaps("name of your map")[0] #0= first map it finds that matches that name
lyrList = m.listLayers()
for lyr in lyrList:
   lyr.visible = False
```

Comment: I tried this out, but now it gives me this error..... `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You'll need to do some reading on how listMaps works off the project class: how to use the wild card search and the return type.